# Ansible - Unarchive specifics files from war archive

Tags: spring-boot, ansible, redhat

I would like to extract two files from directory from war archive.

The two files exists in **/WEB-INF/classes/**

I have tried:

```yaml
- name: create application.properties in /tmp
  unarchive:
    src: "/application/webapps/application.war"
    dest: "/tmp"
    remote_src: yes
    extra_opts:
      - -j
      - WEB-INF/classes/application.properties
      - WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml
```

Error :

> "err":"unzip:  cannot find or open /WEB-INF/classes/application.properties"

But it doesn't work of course. Any idea?

Comment: Any idea please?

Comment: It is running `unzip` on the `.war` file. Not sure if it works on `war` files. Try `list_files` in your task to see if it returns the list of files.

Comment: @Seshadri_C how can i do that ?

Comment: You can add `list_files: yes` instead of `extra_opts:`.

Comment: @Seshadri_C with list_files it can list all the files of war

Comment: Your path should be `WEB-INF/classes/application.properties` and `WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml`, I guess but, then, `extra_opts` does not seems to be handling non-options parameters really well, so you have to make odd things to make it work as it should. Maybe you should use the `unzip` command from a shell instead?

Comment: The issue really with `extra_opts` is that ansible is constructing the command this way (well not exactly but that's a Jinja representation of it): `unzip -o {{ extra_opts | join(' ') }} {{ src }} -d {{ dest }}` and so when you are using non-options, the parameters ends up being considered as the archive path :/

Comment: yes if use unzip command its work, but i need to use unarchive command

Comment: An `ansible-playbook -vvvv` test of mine on this `cmd": ["/usr/bin/unzip", "-o", "-j", "WEB-INF/classes/application.properties", "WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml", "/tmp/test.war", "-d", "/tmp/out"],`

Comment: i tried many solution but they aren't work with me

Comment: None will really I fear. The best I could come with does work but errors with and ugly `"err": "caution: filename not matched:  /tmp/test.war\n",` because of the issue prompted above. Related is this feature request on their tracker https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27081

Comment: So honestly, if you really want it, I could provide you my solution, but I don't think it is a really nice approach I ended up with, tbh.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε could you please provide me your solution ?

Comment: I also feel that it is easier and cleaner to use `unzip` with Ansible `command:` module. Especially since it supports `-u` (update) so we are not really getting anything significantly better by using the module.

Comment: This said I am really baffled on how [this line](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/files/unarchive.py#L558) ends up generating the wrong output I get...

Comment: Oh, that repo is outdated, the issue is there indeed: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/3e9943bc5e7a9cd393757aa8100d7fed80bd316e/lib/ansible/modules/unarchive.py#L596

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really it looks like Ansible `unarchive` module is not meant of this specific use case.
And there is a feature request to actually implement [this exact feature](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27081).

Long story short: `extra_opts` is meant for options, but does not seems be be meant for extra parameters.

What you are looking to do seems like it was possible before [this commit](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/12628ed7e538e9c074a026240744ab9c46954797), indeed, before this commit, Ansible would do:

```py
cmd = [ self.cmd_path, '-o', self.src ]
if self.opts:
    cmd.extend(self.opts)
```

And so you will end with the command:

```bash
unzip -o /application/webapps/application.war -j \
  WEB-INF/classes/application.properties \
  WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml
```

That **should have worked** in your use case.
But after this commit, Ansible's code ends up being

```py
cmd = [ self.cmd_path, '-o' ]
if self.opts:
    cmd.extend(self.opts)
cmd.append(self.src)
```

And so, it generates this **buggy** `unzip` command:

```bash
unzip -o -j \
  WEB-INF/classes/application.properties \
  WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml \
  /application/webapps/application.war
```

---

Now you could work around this bug, but this will make `unzip` error, and  we will have to sweep this error under the rug, so this should not be the solution of your choice.

But here is the train of thought I went in and what I did to have a working playbook: I identified the issue with the command using `ansible-playbook play.yml -vvvv`, that got me the full `unzip` command issued by Ansible — the error below has been reduced for brevity:

```json
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "dest": "/tmp/out",
    "extract_results": {
        "cmd": [
            "/usr/bin/unzip",
            "-o",
            "-j",
            "WEB-INF/classes/application.properties",
            "WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml",
            "test.war",
            "-d",
            "/tmp/out"
        ]
    }
}
```

Based on this, I **tricked** the `extra_opts` by reproducing the archive in the `src` parameter, so it fits right after the option `-j` in the command.

The drawback of this is that is is now generating this command:

```bash
unzip -o -j \
  test.war \
  WEB-INF/classes/application.properties \
  WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml \
  test.war
```

Which means that it is now trying to find the file *test.war* inside itself, and so, it will error because of this.

Here is the errors this yields:

> "err": "caution: filename not matched:  test.war\n"

So once again, I used **a trick** with the help of [`failed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure) to ignore this error, knowing the error it would yield me.

So, given:

```
$ tree ./WEB-INF
./WEB-INF
└── classes
    ├── application.properties
    ├── ignore-me.txt
    └── logback.xml

1 directory, 3 files

$ tree /tmp
/tmp

0 directories, 0 files
```

And the tasks:

```yaml
 - shell: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin/jar -cf test.war *

- file:
    path: /tmp/out
    state: directory

- unarchive: 
    src: test.war
    dest: /tmp/out
    remote_src: yes
    extra_opts:
      - -j
      - test.war
      - WEB-INF/classes/application.properties
      - WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml
  register: extract
  failed_when: 
    - extract.extract_results.rc != 0
    - "extract.extract_results.err != 'caution: filename not matched:  ' 
        ~ extract.src ~ '\n'"
```

You end up with those files:

```
/ansible # tree /tmp/out
/tmp/out
├── application.properties
└── logback.xml

0 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation.It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is preferable to use Ansible modules as much as possible. In this scenario, using the `unzip` command with appropriate options (`-u` = update) can be just as efficient and [*simple*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#keep-it-simple).

Example snippet below:

```yaml
  tasks:
  - command: 'unzip -j -u /application/webapps/application.war {{ item }} -d /tmp'
    with_items:
      - 'WEB-INF/classes/application.properties'
      - 'WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml'
    args:
      warn: false
```

Comment: thanks, but i already use this solution, but as i said i want to use the command of ansible Unarchive .. instead of unzip  command